# Why do I have to reseat GPU after cutting power?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I don't really need a solution, per se, but I'm really curious if anyone knows why this happens.

So, I recently cleaned my PC and when I tried to boot up the PC again, an all too familiar conundrum came my way.
This is what happened.

I put the power cord back in and try to boot up the PC like normal. And 2 problems appear:

- There's no signal to the screen *(like at all - no boot up process, nothing)*
- The PC reboots **once** and then seems to runs fine afterwards. *(except the no signal)*

Given the fact, that I've encountered this issue before I've found the "solution" to be taking out my GPU and letting the PC boot with the internal graphics chip. Then shut the PC off and reseat the GPU -- afterwards it boots up just fine.

Does anyone know why this happens? Or rather, why I have to do this?

Specs:

- MB: ASUS P8Z77 LX2
- CPU: Intel i5-3570k
- GPU: AMD RX 480
- PSU: Corsair 550W

Comment: Basic information about your computer model, video card model, etc. would be very helpful for us to have a better idea of what you are seeing. The short answer is that the motherboard is having trouble deciding which video adapter to use it sounds like - that's probably a BIOS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously stated, it's likely to be a BIOS issue where the BIOS can't determine which GPU to use. Since your motherboard is very similar to mine there is the possibility that the setting for this is very similar. Even if not the info below will give you a starting point.
Get into the BIOS: boot and keep tapping on the DEL key. 
Select Advanced, 
Select System Agent Configuration, 
Select Graphics Configuration, 
Select Primary Display and set it to PCIe, 
Exit the BIOS with SAVE the settings and that may do the job for you.